# How can I open id0, id1, nam, so, or til files?

Tags: android, java

I am attempting to reverse engineer the DYMO Connect app in order to learn how to print to a DYMO LabelWriter Wireless printer. However, the mobile driver for the printer is in several different formats: id0, id1, nam, so, and til. Is there any way that I can open any one of these files so that I can see what code they wrote for the driver? I have searched about this question a lot, but the answers are not very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id0, id1, nam and til files - are the temporary files which IDA creates when you load your binary into it. And after you close IDA, choosing to save the disassembly result, it's going to delete those files and save idb file instead. Idb - is a binary file where IDA stores disassembly information, so you need to open it with IDA in order to see what's inside. Since the only extension left is .so, I suppose that was the extension of the driver.